# Edit menu 5 column to 4 column css

Tags: css, drop-down-menu

I am pretty new here and I don't  know a lot about coding. I have this wordpress template and i want to adjust the 5 column dropdown menu to a 4 column menu. How can I adjust it?

```
.dropdown-menu .five-col {
    margin: 0 -15px;
}

.dropdown-menu .five-col .column {
    float: left;
    padding: 0 15px;
    width: 20%;
    position: relative;
}

.dropdown-menu .five-col .column:first-child:before {
    display: none;
}

.dropdown-menu .five-col .column:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: -10px;
    background: #181818;
    width: 1px;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}

.dropdown-menu .five-col ul {
    display: block;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.dropdown-menu .five-col ul li {
    display: block;
    width: auto;
    margin: 0;
}

.dropdown-menu .five-col ul li a {
    padding-left: 0;
}

.dropdown-menu .five-col ul li a:hover {
    padding-left: 5px;
}

.dropdown-menu .five-col ul {
    position: static !important;
    width: auto !important;
}

.dropdown-menu .five-col .sub-link-opener {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

[A screenshot can be found here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eJv07.png)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't see your html but maybe you could start give it a four-col class instead of five-col.. anyway you have to change your html structure not only css

Answer (score 0):

Just only css is hard to give exact answer. But i  think you could change width from 20%( 5 columns) to 25% (4 columns)

```
.dropdown-menu .five-col .column{
Width: 25%;
}
```